# Assigning permission to an IIS application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, permissions, window

I have a .NET C# WebAPI running on IIS. The API is served on port 80 and, as part of its duties, connects to a local database service on a very specific port.

By default IIS assigns the built in account `ApplicationPoolIdentity` but it turned out to be too limited in terms of privileges: the app couldn't connect to the local database service.

I tried setting a custom account, an administrator, and it worked

[image]

I don't like the idea of having an IIS app running as administator. Is it possible to elevate the privileges of the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` user and give to it the bare minimum to work properly?

How can I specify the user to use on the web.config file?

Comment: *the app couldn't connect to the local database service* Why not?

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's being blocked by Windows. Proof is that assigning admin right to the app then it works

Comment: Then why you can't assign the proper right or use SQL Server authentication?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can assign the proper right to the app by assigning to it an administrator user. Unfortunately this is a manual settings to be done after the sofware is installed but I don't want the customers to do it as well, it has to be done automatically. Moreover, the customer's Windows7 machine may not have an administator set

Comment: But why can't you connect using SQL Server authentication?

Comment: @PatrickHofman because the local service is not a SQL database, it's a Flexera license manager, I said it was a generic local service to simplify the question removing (what I thought) was unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server is running on the same machine and you aren't using a domain user account to set up the app pool, then you can elevate the permissions of the default app pool identity in SQL Server (or any app pool identity for that matter). The default app pool user should be 'IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool'. Replace the 'DefaultAppPool' with whatever app pool name you want if you don't want to use the default.